# Timeout expired in asp.net with sql server

Tags: asp.net

The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may check the connection and query timeout with sql queries which are used in the program, and FYI sql standard connection timeout-15 secs and query timeout-30 secs,